# From a local branch pull master it's hang

Tags: git, github

In Git I am working in a local branch.
I need to take a pull from origin's master branch. So from local branch run a pull command.

```
git pull origin master

Password for 'xxx': 
From xxxx
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Auto-merging "file name"
Auto-merging "file name"
```

After auto-merging it's hung. nothing happens. After that I click CTRL+C, it stopped.

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple from your local branch:

```
git fetch origin && git merge origin/master
```